# Can't figure out why my function is not being called

Tags: c#

Not sure how stackoverflow questions work, but I am trying to piggy-back off my earlier issue.

I have got rid of all the errors and dig is not null anymore because I actually needed it to have a value and I realized that from people's help earlier but now my function is not being called.

What am I missing??

"Dig" is defined early in my code (`public string dig = default;`)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\Test.txt"))
    {
        int numpins = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        string basepin = textBox2.Text;
        int pinlength = basepin.Length;
        string formatspecifier = "{0:d" + pinlength.ToString() + "}";
        long pinnumber = long.Parse(basepin);

        for (int d = 0; d < numpins; d++)
        {
            dig = basepin;
            if (dig == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("null value not allowed");
            }
            else
            {
                GetCheckDigit(dig);
            }

            basepin = string.Format(formatspecifier, pinnumber);
            objWriter.WriteLine(basepin);
            pinnumber++;
        }

        objWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

This is my function

```
private static string GetCheckDigit(string dig)
{
    var sum = 0;
    var result = true;
    var digits = dig.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = digits.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var num = digits[i] - 48;
        if (result)
        {
            num *= 2;
            if (num > 9)
                num -= 9;
        }
        sum += num;
        result = !result;
    }

    if ((sum % 10) == 0)
    {
        return "0";
    }

    return (10 - (sum % 10)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code and step through it so you can see what's happening.

Comment: "now my function is not being called." How do you know this? Have you run it in the debugger to see what the value of `numpins` and `basepin` are? Have you debugged the `Dig` function to make sure it is working as expected?

Comment: One obvious thing is that you're not capturing the _result_ of your function call, so it _effectively_ does nothing.

Comment: Yes I have debugged it and it bypass the function which is at the end of my code (so it should skip down to it) (dig does have a value) but it does not run the function it just keeps running my loop

Comment: yea I created the checkdigit function and ran it before adding it to this code so I know it works separately

Comment: If `dig` is not `null` (which it won't ever be since you set it to the value of a `TextBox.Text` property, which never returns `null`) and `numpins` is greater than `0`, then your function *will* be called. If the textbox is empty, however, then `digits` will also be empty, and the `for` loop will not execute. Step through the code (including stepping into the method call) and examine the values so you understand what is happening.

Comment: Also, when checking for empty strings, use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)`, not `s == null`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: It's _very_ weird that you're not doing anything with `d` or the result of `GetCheckDigit`. I suspect that it _is_ being run, but since you don't capture the result you don;t _see_ the effect.

Comment: dont you just to attribute the result of your method to a variable?
 something like `string result = GetCheckDigit(dig);`

Comment: THANK YOU to everyone on this post. I have it working and it was reading the function, i do not know why i was thinking it would drop down to the code itself but string result = GetCheckDigit(dig) worked. I debugged my code and the results are what is expected.  Thank you all once again!!!  I needed to capture my results like what was said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless numpins is lower than 0 or basepin is null, `GetCheckDigit(dig)` is being called.
In case you meant it doesn't output anything to the screen it's because
`GetCheckDigit(dig)` doesn't output anything to screen, just returns the string.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what was happening,  Thank you for your answer.